# Configure Memcache per environment

Tags: cache

Is there any way to add memcache servers to use per environment? I mean, one server for dev, one for staging and one for production.

Answer (score 2):

Your `craft/config/memcache.php` config file has the same [multi-environment config](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs) support as any other of Craft's config files.

You can see all the default memcache config options Craft ships with in `craft/config/etc/config/defaults/memcache.php`.